# Error when trying to split a string

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

I'm trying to split a string but there is an error in:

```
ban = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Split(xml, "<item jid='", -1,
      Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Binary)
```

this is full code

```
Dim ban As String  
xml = xml.Replace("\\\", ")  
If (xml.IndexOf("<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>") >= 0) Then  
    If (xml.IndexOf("affiliation='outcast'") >= 0) Then  
        xml = xml.Substring(xml.IndexOf("<item jid='") + 11)  
        xml = xml.Replace("' affiliation='outcast' /></query></iq>", "").Replace("' affiliation='outcast' />", "")  
        xml = xml.Replace("role='participant' />", "")  
        ban = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Split(xml, "<item jid='", -1, Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Binary)  
        ListBox2.Items.Clear()  
        For t = LBound(ban) To UBound(ban)  
            ListBox2.Items.Add(ban(t))  
            info.Text = "List ban Count {" + ListBox2.Items.Count + "}"  
        Next  
    End If  
End If
```

Comment: You did not close your quote on the second line unless that was just a typo in moving it over

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read this on how to ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.  How about showing us the error message.  We are not mind readers.

Comment: There are much, much, much better ways to deal with parsing XML than string functions.  LINQ to XML is one of them.  Can you post the XML? Along with what it is you're trying to use the split for?

Comment: @Abbaskhan - You're going about this the hard way.  Use an XML API to do this.  Post your XML and I can give you an example.

Comment: @Abbaskhan - That doesn't tell us anything.  If you post the entire XML someone can show you either how to make your current code work or any of several alternative, much easier ways to do this.  But we need to see the XML.

Comment: Split() returns an array of strings, not just a single string.

Comment: ban = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Split(xml, "<item jid='", -1, Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Binary) there is error

Comment: xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>"

Answer (score 3):

Ok...a little bit of research on the available code snippet lead me to [this](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#ban).  So, assuming the XML document looks something like this:

```
<iq from='kinghenryv@shakespeare.lit/throne'
    id='ban1'
    to='southampton@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    type='set'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>
    <item affiliation='outcast'
          jid='earlofcambridge@shakespeare.lit'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

Note, there's probably more to the XML than this, but it'll work for purposes of demonstration.  Using string methods to parse XML is the hard way, IMO.  Using an XML API (like LINQ to XML) is much easier.

Here's an example with LNQ to XML.

```
Dim xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml)
Dim ns as XNamespace = "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin"

Dim query = From x in xDoc.Descendants(ns + "item")
            Where x.Attribute("affiliation").Value = "outcast"
            Select x.Attribute("jid").Value
```

The above code loads the XML string into an XDocument. It also sets the namespace (which is contained in the `query` element.

Then a query is conducted against the XML.  It collects all the `item` nodes that have an attribute of `affiliation` with a value of "outcast", and then returns the corresponding `jid` value.

You can then iterate over the collection like this:

```
For Each jid As String In query

    ListBox2.Items.Add(jid)   
Next

info.Text = "List ban Count {" + ListBox2.Items.Count.ToString() + "}"
```

**Edited To Add**

If you still prefer to do it the way your code is doing it, try the following change:

```
Dim ban As String()

ban = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Split(xml, "<item jid='", -1, _
  Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Binary)
```

As others have pointed out, `Split` returns an array, and you have defined `ban` as a String instead of a String() [array].

Comment: @Abbaskhan - See my edit in the For Each loop in my answer above.

Comment: @Tim Not only easier but for most, performance improvement, although a DOM XML parser is not fast or resource friend as a SAX one.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento - I'm not familiar with SAX parsers (heard of them, but never seen one or used one).  I'll have to look into when I get time.

Comment: @Abbaskhan - what is `xml`?  Is it a stream?  Try `XDocument.Load(xml)` in that case.

Comment: @Abbaskhan - then you need to use the `Load` method - `XDocument.Load(xml)`.  Also, you can search online for C# to VB.NET code converters - there are several out there.

Comment: @Abbaskhan - Also, another user just point out my code was wrong for VB.NET with the XDocument - it should be `Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(xml)` or `.Parse(xml)`.  See the edit

Comment: @Abbaskhan - I suggest posting the converted code (as a **NEW** question), along with what errors you are getting and where (in the code) you are getting them.  The more information you provide upfront, the more likely we can help you.

Comment: `var` is a C# keyword.  Try `Dim t As Integer = ban.GetLowerBound(0)`.  By the way, it's really hard to help you when you keep posting code snippets in the comments.  Try editing your question and posting updates there - but **please** include as much information as possible.

Comment: I don't run chat clients.  You can e-mail the C# code if you'd like - my e-mail address is in my profile (click on my name to see my profile).